# How to extract text inside first pair of colons

Tags: sed, grep, text

I have a log file that saves this kind of lines every time a file cannot be extracted from a tar.

```
tar: foto/201802131354184186718718.xml: No se puede efectuar open: File exists
tar: foto/201802131365468046840684.xml: No se puede efectuar open: File exists
```

I need to get the text inside the first pair of colons ":"

Example

```
foto/201802131354184186718718.xml
foto/201802131365468046840684.xml
```

I've tried using grep but i get this:

```
$ grep -oP '\:\K[^\:]+' 20180213.tmp 
 foto/201802131354184186718718.xml
 No se puede efectuar open
 File exists
 foto/201802131365468046840684.xml
 No se puede efectuar open
 File exists
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the easiest way to do this is with other tools, e.g. `cut -d: -f2 20180213.tmp`, `awk -F: '{print $2}' 20180213.tmp`.

However, I also wanted to explain why your `grep` method fails. This is because it matches *all* strings after a `:`. To fix it, you can match the first `:` in the regex with only the first one in the processed line, by adding `^[^\:]*` in front of it. Thus, any character before your original regex cannot be `:`. The full command is:

```
grep -oP '^[^\:]*\:\K[^\:]+' 20180213.tmp
```

Also note that you don't need to escape `:` in the regex, so you can simplify it further with:

```
grep -oP '^[^:]*:\K[^:]+' 20180213.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed using other tools like cut is the best way, but I want to throw out there a sed solution as well:

```sh
sed -r 's/^[^:]+: ?([^:]+):.*/\1/' 20180213.tmp
```

It searches from the start of the line up to the second colon, only characters that are not ':', but keeps only what is in between the first and second colon. I've noticed there's a space right before the file names, so I removed it.